# Python threading won't work twice even though it's in a loop

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I tried making a tic-tac-toe game. Every time the player presses a key, the computer presses one right after. I wanted to make a timer between the computer press and the player press. I wanted to do it with threading otherwise it won't work because the timer will start when the player presses the board and not after. For some reason the threading function won't work more than once.

```
def computer_pressed(btn):
#the button are alredy deactivated
btn['underline'] = 1 #the btn is the button on the board which the computer wants to press
#the underline is a flag, meaning-press the button with underline=1

def wait(theBoard): #the threading
while True:
    for plate in theBoard:
        if theBoard[plate]['underline'] == 1:
            time.sleep(2) #the timer
            theBoard[plate].configure(text = COMPUTER, highlightbackground = "#c7eaeb",
                                      underline = -1) #presses the button
            activate_buttons(theBoard) #activates the button again
```

from main:

```
x = threading.Thread(target=wait, args=(theBoard, )) #the board consists all buttons in board
x.start()
```

All works well the first time, then the second:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/Desktop/tic.py", line 107, in wait
    if theBoard[plate]['underline'] == 1:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1643, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame2.!button3"
```

Invalid command? Why whould it even sat invalid command?

Thank you all for the help

Comment: Hi, 
Seem strange to call a for x in y and than call y[x][z]. You should do  ""if plate['underline'] == 1:"" instead of ""if theBoard[plate]['underline'] == 1:"" exemple
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-for-loop-tutorial/

Comment: `invalid command name ".!frame2.!button3"` means you're trying to modify a button widget after it has been destroyed, or in a tcl interpreter where it hasn't ever been created.